# How to properly use Storage::url( ) in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get my image urls with `Storage::url()`, however it returns the image url without the port number like so `http://localhost/storage/public/yx9zZBbXMTiCH5aICGSRBKfgmDuwxGxuNUi3MwR6.jpg`, and the images are not displaying at all. However if I copy the image url, paste it in the browser address bar and manually append the port number it works fine. Like so `http://localhost:8000/storage/public/yx9zZBbXMTiCH5aICGSRBKfgmDuwxGxuNUi3MwR6.jpg`. What could be wrong?

```
return view('livewire.image-upload', [
            'images' => collect(Storage::files('public'))
                ->filter(function ($file) {
                    return in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'webp']);
                })
                ->map(function ($file) {
                    return Storage::url($file);
                })
        ]);
```

Comment: Is your `APP_URL` set correctly in your .env file?

Comment: I guess you have `APP_URL=http://localhost` in your .env file

Comment: Ok. I just corrected it and it worked. Don't know why that didn't occur to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit App URL in env file

Ex:-

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```